# Excel How to find all the values from cell A that do not exist in cell B

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 Columns A,B,C and D

```
038871011        1600         038521011             2100
038561011        4200         038871011             1600
038521011        3200         038571011             1407
038571011        1407         038881516             18000
```

A and C represent phone numbers and B and D their respective month charge

I want to write in column E the phone numbers from A that do not exist in C with their month charge in F, and write in G the phone numbers from C that do not exist in A with their month charge in H, using visual basic

Comment: So what's the problem?  Do you know how to code in VBA? If No, then this is not the place to learn - lots of very good tutorials out there.  If Yes, then what have you already tried, and what happened?

Comment: you can do this without vba, via `IFERROR` and `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 0):

As someone said above, this is quite easy with Vlookup and Iferror. You don't really need VBA. If you do, try to build on the below
Try this and let me know if it works.

In Column E paste the below

```
 Column E =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$4,1,0),"")
```

In Column F paste the below

```
 Column F =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$B$4,2,0),"")
```

I will leave it to you to try Column G and H. Let me know how it goes. 
I tested it and it works.

Comment: thank you for your answer but what i wanted is completely the opposite, the iferror vlookup function return the element that exists in both A and C, and what i want is the elements that exist in A and DO NOT exist in C

Comment: @AliAllaoua the change the above to `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$4,1,0)),C1,"")`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$4,0)),"",C1)